# Выполнить curl в bash скрипте через QProcess

Tags: linux, bash, консоль, curl, shell

Есть bash скрипт, который должен скачивать архив, распаковывать его и удалять. В скрипт передается индекс файла, который нужно скачивать. Выглядит следующим образом:

```
curl -o file.zip http://any-dev.com/get/$1 && \
unzip file.zip && \
rm file.zip
```

Скрипт лежит в ресурсах Qt (**.qrc**). И запускается плюсовым кодом:

```
const QString param(QString::number(value));
if (!QFile::exists(":/screepts/screept.txt"))
   qDebug() << "File not exists" << endl;
 
QFile file(":/screepts/screept.txt");
if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    qDebug() << "File not open" << endl;
 
const QString command = QString(R"(%1 %2)")
        .arg(QString(file.readAll()).replace("\n", " "))
        .arg(param);
 
qDebug() << command <<endl;
QProcess::startDetached("bash", {"-c", command});
```

Плюсовый код по запуску скрипта работает нормально. Проблемы видимо в самом скрипте. В консоле ошибки:

> % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time
> Current
> Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed 100  6607    0  6607    0     0  49074      0 --:--:-- --:--:--
> --:--:-- 49305 /usr/bin/bash: line 1:  unzip: command not found

Пример вывода дебага:

```
"curl -o file.zip http://any-dev.com/get/$1 && \\ unzip file.zip && \\ rm file.zip  200"
```

Comment: unzip: command not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> В скрипт передается индекс файла, который нужно скачивать. Выглядит
> следующим образом:
>
> ```
>     curl -o file.zip http://any-dev.com/get/$1 && \
>     unzip file.zip && \
>     rm file.zip
> ```

не нужно использовать вместе `&& \`, для переноса записи здесь и одного `&&` будет достаточно.

у вас вылазит ошибка

```
/usr/bin/bash: line 1: unzip: command not found
```

сам `unzip` на скока я понял у вас установлен, но из за того что перенос строки `\n` после `\` вырезается `...replace("\n", " "))` то следующая команда уже не отработает как надо.

пример:

```
$ echo 111 &&
echo 444
111
444
```

будет работать как и

```
$ echo 111 && \
echo 444
111
444
```

но если в одной строке, то

```
$ echo 111 && \ echo 444
1111
bash:  echo: команда не найдена
```

Comment: Действительно, добавление разделения команд && помогло. А как подставить число в url? Параметр не подставляется в url. bash -c "curl -o file.zip http://any-dev.com/get/$1 && unzip file.zip && rm file.zip 95"

Comment: @ZeusBios я так понимаю вы запускаете не сам bash-скрипт как таковой а цепочку из нескольких утилит(curl, unzip, rm) через bash-интерпретатор в который и пытаетесь передать `индекс файла` ?

Comment: Да верно. Я читаю файл где команды (это txt). И запускаю так: bash -c "commands". И в первую команду curl надо передать индекс файла, чтобы он в урлу встал.

Comment: @ZeusBios тогда  аргументы нужно дописывать в конце, пример: `bash -c 'echo аргумент1=$0 аргумент2=$1' r1 r2` выведет `аргумент1=r1 аргумент2=r2`

Comment: Я ведь его и дописываю в конце. Вот так формируется строка: const QString command = QString(R"(%1 %2)")
        .arg(QString(file.readAll()).replace("\n", " "))
        .arg(param);
Т.е. сначала идет цепочка команд из файла, а затем аргумент последним

Comment: @ZeusBios я не силён в с++/qt но учитывайте что `$1` в `http://any-dev.com/get/$1` для **обычного** bash-скрипта это первый аргумент, но вот при такой записи `bash -c ...` первым аргументом уже будет `$0`

Comment: Hработает вот так: bash -c 'curl -o file.zip http://any-dev.com/get/$0 && unzip file.zip && rm file.zip' 95

Comment: Благодарю вас. Спасибо

Comment: @ZeusBios попробуйте вместо двойных использовать одинарные кавычки

Comment: Все равно не работает

Comment: Когда ручками вводишь, работает. Когда ту же самую строку запускаешь в апе. Не работает

Comment: @ZeusBios затык по видимому уже где-то в c++/qt коде. Еще можете попробовать запускать код через файл где лежат bash-команды: `bash file.sh аргумент1` где в файле **первый** аргумент это уже `$1`

Comment: Изменил формирование параметров для QProcess. На     QStringList args("-c");
    args << QString(file.readAll()).replace("\n", " ");
    args << param; И теперь работает все. Фух